# "ErrorReply: ERR invalid expire time in 'set' command" for using redis package in nodejs typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis

redis.set command caused the error. Here is sources

```
private async setStatus(key: string, status: Status) {
    const primary = await RedisPrimary.getInstance();
    await primary.set(key, `${status}`);
  }
```

The following is the function set in RedisPrimary.

```
async set(key: string, value: string, expire: number = 0): Promise<boolean> {
    const resultSet = await this.client.set(key, value, { EX: expire });
    return resultSet === "OK";
  }
```

And then, `this.client.set` caused the following error.
`[ErrorReply: ERR invalid expire time in 'set' command]`

Shortly, I intended to set key with expire time as zero, which means no expiration, but the invalid expire time occurred. Why this happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [SET](https://redis.io/commands/set/) command cannot be used with an expiration time or TTL of 0.

Note that if you don't specify an expiration time - the default is no expiry:

> Any previous time to live associated with the key is discarded on successful SET operation.

You can verify it from the Redis API:

```
redis> SET x 5 EX 0
(error) ERR invalid expire time in 'set' command
redis> SET x 5 PX 0
(error) ERR invalid expire time in 'set' command
redis> SET x 5 EXAT 0
(error) ERR invalid expire time in 'set' command
redis> SET x 5 PXAT 0
(error) ERR invalid expire time in 'set' command
redis> SET x 5 EX 1
OK
redis> SET x 5 PX 1
OK
redis> SET x 5 EXAT 1
OK
redis> SET x 5 PXAT 1
OK
redis> SET x 5
OK
```